# What does Semaphor.drainPermits do if no permits are available?

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm trying to understand the contract of drainPermits in the Java Semaphore class

The JavaDoc simply reads:

> public int drainPermits()
>
> ```
> Acquire and return all permits that are immediately available.
>
> Returns:
>     the number of permits
> ```

If no permits are currently available, does it block and wait until one is available?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it will return 0 immediately. It doesn't require any permits to be available.

Comment: So if I am reviewing code where it looks like somebody might have been using it for locking, they're in for a nasty surprise, right?

Comment: It depends on exactly what they're doing. "Using it for locking" doesn't really give much of a hint.

Comment: if they are initializing it to 1 and using drain to implement 
a "tryAcquire" it is fine. 

In many different languages and systems, many implementations of a (non-nesting) mutex is a semaphore initialized to 1.